# How to disable messages generated by RAISE INFO

Tags: database, postgresql

I have many functions in my postgresql DB. Many of them have these lines

```
RAISE INFO 'Some step completed';
RAISE NOTICE 'Some step completed';
```

What should I do to not display them in the query results?

Thousands of this messages slows down query execution time. I tried `SET client_min_messages TO warning`, but it disabled only `NOTICE` message types and I still see `INFO`.

Comment: This has something to do with the fact, that `INFO` level is not sorted on the `client_min_messages`' description page, but it is on the `log_min_messages`' one. Plus, they have different orderings. That suggests `INFO` messages cannot be turned off on the client, but can be turned off in the logs.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES

Comment: @pozs Documentation says `The default is WARNING.` for `client_min_messages` and I do have this default value in my config file.

Comment: see at "Valid values". `INFO` aren't in them. And *The default is `NOTICE`* for `client_min_messages`.

Comment: @pozs oh, sorry. I meand for `log_min_messages`. Documentation says `The default is WARNING`. for `log_min_messages`